# Write an ID into session as a variable

Tags: php, session

I need to insert an ID into session for later use. Table contains ID, username and password.
To get the ID im using:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

And trying to store it into session:

```
$_SESSION["id"] = $result;
```

When im trying to insert $_SESSION[id] into a table I get the value of 0 (which is the default value I made).

Kinda new on PHP, any help would be appriciated :)

Answer (score 1):

you need fetch the value aswell:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$fetch =mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION["id"] = $fetch["ID"];
```

Comment: change the variable $fetch, to something more suitable depending on your application!

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource.

You need to use a function to access the resource returned:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
$id = $row['id'];
```

The proper way to handle result would be to first check it has any value at all, i.e.:

```
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) You need to fetch the rows from that result:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row){ // check that there was really selected at least one row
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}
```